# What is happening with my reference variables?

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the hang of references in C++ (I think I've got it in Java and in Javascript, but the transition is harder than I imagined).
Here's a snipet of code, the result of which I don't understand:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> x;
    x.push_back(1);

    std::vector<int> y;
    y.push_back(2);
    
    std::vector<int>& r=x;
    r.push_back(3);
    
    std::vector<int>& s=r;
    s.push_back(4);
    
    s=y;
    r.push_back(5);
    s.push_back(6);
    
    std::cout<<"x: ";
    for(int i: x) {std::cout<< i<< " ";} std::cout<<"\n";
    
    std::cout<<"y: ";
    for(int i: y) {std::cout<< i<< " ";} std::cout<<"\n";
    
}
```

I get the following output (using g++ 4.9.2):

> x: 2 5 6
>
> y: 2

I don't understand this: what have become of elements 1, 3, 4 ? I would have expected x to be 1,3,4,5 and y to be 2,6. Does the fact of having vectors of ints makes a difference?

Comment: `s=y;` means `x=y` and `s` will continue referring to `x`. It doesn't mean `s` will refer to `y`.

Comment: @Nawaz: Buddy, the answer section is down there:  ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm lazy.. and you've already answer it well. Nothing to add more.

Comment: @Nawaz: Then no need to write the answer again. Just say nothing. Certainly not in the _comments_ section, which is for critiquing, for requesting clarification, and for having stupid arguments like this. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I didn't write it *again*. I wrote it once before I refreshed the page.

Comment: @Nawaz: "One more" (as Vlad would say), please do not write answers in the comment section. Thanks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That is *not* an answer. Just a hint which needs elaboration.

Comment: @Nawaz: SO is not for "hints which need elaboration". Answer or don't. Gosh you should know this stuff :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Comments dont have that *strict* rules. At least you don't follow this yourself  which you're preaching here ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Important point: *references are non-reseatable.* Once you initialise a reference, it will *always* refer to the same object.

Now let's analyse your code step by step:

```
std::vector<int> x;
x.push_back(1);
```

`x` is a vector which contains `1`.

```
std::vector<int> y;
y.push_back(2);
```

`y` is a vector which contains `2`.

```
std::vector<int>& r=x;
r.push_back(3);
```

`r` is a reference to `x`, which now contains `1 3`.

```
std::vector<int>& s=r;
s.push_back(4);
```

`s` is a reference to `x`, which now contains `1 3 4`.

```
s=y;
```

Now, you've copied the vector `y` to the vector `x` (through reference `s` which refers to it). That replaces the contents of `x` with the contents of `y`, which is `2`.

```
r.push_back(5);
s.push_back(6);
```

`x` (to which both `r` and `s` refer) now contains `2 5 6`.

`y` was never modified after the single `push_back` after its creation, and so it contains just `2`.

---

The concept which Java calls "references" is actually what "pointers" are in C++. With pointers, the code would have looked like this:

```
std::vector<int>* r = &x;
r->push_back(3);

std::vector<int>* s = r;
s->push_back(4);

s = &y;

r->push_back(5);
s->push_back(6);
```

Then, `x` would contain `1 3 4 5`, and `y` would contain `2 6`.

Notice that the syntax for creating a pointer to an object (taking the object's address) requires explicit use of the address-of operator `&`. Likewise, dereferencing a pointer requires explicit syntax: `*p` for simply obtaining the object pointed to, or `p->m` for accessing the member `m` of the object pointed to by `p`.

Answer (score 4):

References are bound to an object *once* and can never be reseated. There is simply no syntax for that. As you've seen with your use of e.g. `s.push_back`, whenever you name `s` you are accessing the *referent* `r` (which, by extension, is actually `x`).

So, `s=y` does not make the reference refer to the other vector. What you're doing here is the same as `x=y`. All the elements originally in `x` are lost.

Reference semantics in Java bear approximately zero relation to reference semantics in C++. You'd do well to immediately cease trying to compare the two, or to "transition" from one to the other. Come to C++ with a clean, fresh mind.

Comment: Ok I get it. Is there a simple way to say "I want s to refer to y instead of x"?

Comment: @laurent No. from the answer `References are bound to an object once and can never be reseated`

Comment: @laurent: As I've already said, no. If you really think you need to do it, look at _pointers_ (which are more similar to Java's references) ... but you probably don't.

Answer (score 2):

Assignment `s=y;` where `s` refers to `x`, results in copying `y` to `x` which overwrites (1,3,4). So `x` becomes (2) and then is appended 5 and 6. Meanwhile `y` remains untouched and is finally (2).